# Extending 500us pulse for multiple input signals and minimum IC count

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, pulse

I need to extend as fast as 500us input pulses to ~150ms for them to be detected by a downstream circuit. Pulses are coming from sensors.

I've found other answers in this site and others about using retriggerable monostable multivibrators, but the problem with those solutions is that they don't have enough density, I need to do this for 16 input signals and I haven't found a package with more than 2 monostables, and then I would require to also have an RC circuit for each one.

My current solution is using microcontrollers to detect the signal and set the output high for 150ms for each pulse detected in the corresponding input. Problem is that I'm having some misses with this design at higher speeds, and although I think it should theoretically work, I'm thinking that there might be a discrete solution that more efficiently solves this problem.

Currently, and assuming I get it to work well, I'm using 2x18 pin ICs for this, so looking for something around those numbers, can be higher if it results in more reliable results.

Comment: There's certainly no reason that any modern MCU wouldn't be able to keep up with 16 channels of 500 us pulses. Maybe you should show us your current firmware so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: I certainly agree that it shouldn't be a problem. I'm using a binary from an existing design and I'm unsure how it's implemented. Before starting to write my own software I wanted to know if there was any other solution that didn't need writing software, which I can certainly do but it's been a while since I've written microcontoller software so trying to avoid the ramp up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-chip solution requires a microcontroller with at least 16 inputs and 16 outputs.

500us is a really long time in terms of microcontroller clock cycles.  You can use interrupts that react to input changes or simply poll the inputs, then trigger individual timers for each of the outputs.

Even a lowly PIC running at 4 MHz (1us instruction rate) can do this easily.  Look at groups of 8 inputs (1 byte) and look for changes.  Then reset the timer(s) for any inputs that triggered - while a timer is running, that output pin is active.  When the timer expires, the timer freezes at that count and the output pin is reset.

If you want to do it in hardware instead, consider using the cd4043 quad R-S latch.  Your rising input pulse goes to the Set input of one latch and there is a RC network from each output back to that latch's Reset pin.

16 pulses will cost you 4 IC packages and 16 each resistors and capacitors.

It is permissible to use a 4043 quad latch in this fashion because there aren't any edge-sensitive clock inputs.  This is a reliable technique that has been used in thousands of designs over the years.

Quick, easy, no software to write.